# pandas resample with origin and closed status

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe for inventory like the following,

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2022-10-01', periods=15, freq='D') 
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=['inventory'], index=tidx)
data_frame.iloc[-2:] = 0
print(data_frame)

inventory
2022-10-01          1
2022-10-02          1
2022-10-03          1
2022-10-04          1
2022-10-05          1
2022-10-06          1
2022-10-07          1
2022-10-08          1
2022-10-09          1
2022-10-10          1
2022-10-11          1
2022-10-12          1
2022-10-13          1
2022-10-14          0
2022-10-15          0
```

I want to aggregate for 7 days from any day of the week (here `2020-10-15`). If I do the following, I don't know why the results start from `2020-10-13`

```
data_frame.resample("7D", closed = 'right', origin='2020-10-15').sum()

inventory
2022-09-29  6
2022-10-06  7
2022-10-13  0
```

My desired output is,

```
inventory
2022-09-01  1
2022-10-08  7
2022-10-15  5
```

**Note:** My panda's version is '1.3.5'

Answer (score 1):

```py
data_frame.resample("7D", origin='2022-10-15', closed='right', loffset='7D').sum()
```

Gives:

```
            inventory
2022-10-01          1
2022-10-08          7
2022-10-15          5
```

Although `loffset` is deprecated. So you can do this instead.

```py
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
df = data_frame.resample("7D", origin='2022-10-15', closed='right').sum()
df.index = df.index + to_offset("7D")
```

Additionally, a more elegant solution to this would be:

```py
data_frame.resample("7D", origin='end', closed='right').sum()
```

Comment: I liked your last solution! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found a fair solution,

```
data_frame.resample("W-SAT", closed = 'right').sum()

inventory
2022-10-01  1
2022-10-08  7
2022-10-15  5
```

The only caveat is to calculate the start date name which is `SAT` (for `2022-10-15`)